# If blog post, posted more than 30 days ago remove label 'new' in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to remove 'new' label on the post title for those posted more than 30days ago I tried this in view but not working

```
@foreach ($post as $p)
   @if(\DB::table('post')->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(created_at, now()) > 30')->get())
    emove label goes here ...
   @endif
@endforeach
```

note my label is a gif image so it found in the asset folder

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Why not put that PHP code into your model?

Comment: The code is not working because you are actually not checking the $post model $p is older than 30 days, you are actually executing a query that gets all post models that are older than 30 days.

Comment: @NicoHaase how?

Answer (score 3):

Better solution is to use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).
Ex. your model is Post::class, then add method:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Carbon\Carbon; // not sure need this, tt rm
...
protected $dates = ['created_at'];
...

// Laravel 9+ version:

protected function hasNewLabel(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn () => $this->attributes['created_at']->gt(now()->subDays(30)->endOfDay());
    );
}

// Laravel 8 version:

protected function getHasNewLabelAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['created_at']->gt(now()->subDays(30)->endOfDay());
}
```

then in blade template using like this

```php
@foreach ($posts as $post)
   ...
   @if($post->has_new_label) // !$post->has_new_label if not, and smht inside
    // label html goes here
   @endif
   ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: syntax error on :

Comment: @mne what  php & laravel versions a u using?

Comment: php 7.3.2 and laravel 8.83.27  but still got an error

Comment: These type of accessors didn't work in prior laravel versions, refer to this page in the documentation to see how accessor were used in laravel 8 https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: @if(now()-$post->created_at >30)  remove label @endif, that is what I mean

Comment: I add Laravel 8 version accessor, it shoul work now. The other thing is @mne what do u mean by saying "remove label"? How u adding it ad what is label in ur code? Better add ur blade code

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this in pure PHP or by using [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). For example:

```
 @php
 $date1=date_create('2023-04-01 12:53:00'); //created_at data. Don't forget to replace the date with your created_at value. Ex: $p->created_at
 $date2=date_create(date('Y-m-d h:m:s')); //date now

 
  $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2); // gets the difference between two dates
  $diff=$diff->format("%a"); // format difference 
  if($diff > 30){
    echo "Remove label"; //More than 30 days
  }else{
    echo "Less than 30 days";  //Less than 30 days 
  }
```

@endphp

Comment: Please share more details. Embedding such code into a Blade template is really bad practise